# How to use docker deploy in docker-compose 3?

Tags: image, docker, containers

When I make command `sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test`

```
Ignoring unsupported options: build, external_links, links, restart

Updating service test_cache (id: me2vh1lffrl4ppzomphin167la)
Updating service test_lb (id: ycnne1ifpt517wdbfdg1g5tlup)
Updating service test_media (id: rr3ural9hjz0mw6hjx7n2vywm)
Creating service test_web

Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = ContainerSpec: image reference must be provided
```

And I get this error - **Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = ContainerSpec: image reference must be provided**

But I create image for this container.

Comment: Please include your `docker-compose.yml` for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 19):

Your compose.yml file does not include an image section which is required by `docker stack deploy`.  You should also be pushing these images to a registry server if you are deploying them to a swarm since docker uses pinning to the sha256 of the image in the registry to ensure all nodes run the same image. And since swarm does not build the images, any node without the image included locally will not be able to run this image unless it's pulled from a registry.

Comment: I sign up on docker. Then I login in docker account using command ```docker login```  and write ``` sudo docker push test ```   I get  one more error - denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: Pushing to docker hub requires that your images be named with your login id as a prefix: `login_id/image_name`. You can use `docker tag test:latest login_id/image_name:latest` to retag an existing image.

Comment: It seems to be worked. Now I can use command sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml login_id/image_name for deploying?

Comment: Yes. If your registry is private, you'll want to also include `--with-registry-auth`

Comment: Ohh. Every command make new error  ((  Now it`s-  Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = name must be valid as a DNS name component

Comment: It appears that you've solved your first error. I'd recommend opening a new question with the new error, and be sure to include the contents of your yml file there. See the help section for more details on asking questions, in particular the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but I'd like to say that I got this error when I had a comment in the `docker-compose.yml` file, like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # pull the image from repository
    image: myname/docker-private:testproj
    ...
```

However, the comment needs to start at the first character of the line:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
# pull the image from repository
    image: myname/docker-private:testproj
    ...
```

This fixed the problem.